# Php Recursive function to parse nested xml tags

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, plist, domdocument

I'm trying to parse this XML structure but can't find a way to parse "n"-deep nested tags using recursion.
The xml structure:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <key>1.1.1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>nag</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>

    <key>2.2.2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>nag</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>

    <key>3.3.3</key>
    <dict>
        <key>show_upgrade_button</key>
        <integer>0</integer>

        <key>nag_startup</key>
        <dict>
            <key>nag_gameover</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>

        <key>my_stuff</key>
        <string>1=cb 2=rm 3=cb+rm =leave banner ads off</string>

    </dict>

    <key>4.4.4</key>
    <dict>
        <key>nag</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The nodes are matched `key` - `dict` being the key node a version number for the data inside the `dict` node but the xml structure has arbrittrary `dict` nesting as you can see in the above code. I've got this recursive function which accepts a `dict` node so far but I can't see the light.

```
<? php
function recursiveNodes($nodes, $arr){
        $count=0;
        if($nodes->hasChildNodes() === true  ){ 

            foreach($nodes->childNodes as $node){

                $temp = array();
                if($node->nodeName === 'key'){

                    $temp['key_name'] = $node->nodeValue;
                    if($node->nextSibling->nodeName !== 'dict'){
                        $sibling = $node->nextSibling;                      
                        $temp['type_name'] = $sibling ->nodeName;
                        $temp['value_name'] = $sibling ->nodeValue;
                    }
                    if($sibling->nodeName === 'dict'){
                    return recursiveNodes($sibling, $arr[$count++][]=$temp);
                }   
                }

            }

        }
            return $arr;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this XML? It's not clear what you're actually recursing to find.

Comment: Are you trying to flatten this structure into an array? Are you trying to represent it in a recursive array data structure?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I'm trying to get the `key` nodeValue, and the next `key` sibling data as an array I need that data to insert into the db. Let's say first <key> <dict> pair,
    `<key>1.1.1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>nag</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>`
 from the <key> node I got "1.1.1", from the <dict> node an array with the following data of its children nodes key_name ="nag", type_name= "integer" and type_value="1".

Comment: @nickb yes, the problem it's that I don't know how many nested dicts it will have. And it could be a pair of key-dict inside a dict tag which will have more nested tags or a pair of key-anytag which doesn't have more childnodes

Comment: If recursion gives you troubles with an XML document, look into xpath which is normally able to return you such as a list already. E.g. you can query all `<dict>` elements that have `<key>` as sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion in your function is broken. It might be more easy to wrap it into an object instead of a single function.

That would also allow to more easily extend it as needed.

See the following usage-example:

```
$parser = new PlistXMLParser();
$parser->loadXML($xml);
print_r($parser->parse());
```

With your exemplary input it gives the following:

```
Array
(
    [1.1.1] => Array
        (
            [nag] => 1
        )

    [2.2.2] => Array
        (
            [nag] => 1
        )

    [3.3.3] => Array
        (
            [show_upgrade_button] => 0
            [nag_startup] => Array
                (
                    [nag_gameover] => 3
                )

            [my_stuff] => 1=cb 2=rm 3=cb+rm =leave banner ads off
        )

    [4.4.4] => Array
        (
            [nag] => 1
        )

)
```

Internally this works basically how you already do, see here an excerpt from [the sources](https://gist.github.com/hakre/5933146):

```
...
switch ($type) {
    case self::NODE_INTEGER:
        $result[$keyString] = sprintf('%0.0f', trim($value));
        break;

    case self::NODE_STRING:
        $result[$keyString] = (string)$value;
        break;

    case self::NODE_DICT:
        $parser = new self();
        $parser->loadSimpleXMLElement($value);
        $result[$keyString] = $parser->parse();
        break;

    default:
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Unexpected type "%s" for key "%s"', $type, $key));
}
...
```

The parser is using a `switch` construct to better deal with the individual type-tokens that come up in the XML structure. The exception highlights you features you've not yet implemented and the recursion is triggered for `NODE_DICT` which just instantiates a new parser and let it do the work. A very simple form of recursion.

Comment: thanks alot, it seems that it should be working, when trying to run the code it gives me an operand error `list($value) = $key->xpath('following-sibling::*[1]') + [NULL];` here, line 33, also will this work with an xml with a regular header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ....` thanks again! simple and powerfull code

Comment: The code is written in the oldest current non-end-of-life PHP version: 5.4. Please upgrade PHP to 5.4 minimum or backport the code (`[NULL]` -> `array(NULL)`). And yes, everything of XML that is supported by SimpleXMLElement is support by that one. It's comparable to DOMDocument in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Using SimpleXML library
public function getNodes($root) 
{   
    $output = array();

    if($root->children()) {
        $children = $root->children();   

        foreach($children as $child) {
            if(!($child->children())) {
                $output[] = (array) $child;
            }
            else {
                $output[] = self::getNodes($child->children());
            } 
        }
    }   
    else {
        $output = (array) $root;
    }   

    return $output;
}
```